# AjaxFileUpload not working when code deployed on godaddy windows hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Its working absolutely fine on my local machine.

I designed the application on 4.0 framework, and changed the target framework to 4.5 when I deployed the code.

Web Config File

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"   type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
<add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"     preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

.aspx Code for control

```
 <cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" throbberid="myThrobber"  OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
                                         runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4"></cc1:AjaxFileUpload>
```

[Status bar shows image uploaded 100% but after that it shows error in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoyLd.jpg)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I have given write permission to folder i am uploading, ASP File upload control is working fine, i am facing this issue with AJAX FILE upload control in ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more R and D on control processing and came to know that Ajaxfileupload control, temporarily saves the file in windows  temp directory and when it process save command, it then delete the file in temp and move it to your location.

Since i am uaing shared platform i dont have full permission to it.

I replaced all ajaxfileupload to asyncfileupload, now it works fine.